# Custom Variables in base.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm wondering how I would go about using custom variables in base.html.twig in a symphony application.

I know I can use {{ app.whatever }} but how would I use {{ myvariable }} or {{ myentity.row }} if I wanted to?

Thanks

Comment: You can use any variable while it exist in the view, if you need to do it in the base.html.twig just need to pass the variable in all the actions that use a template extending that base.html.twig.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a variable is rendered with a twig template, you can use this variable in both parent and child templates.

In other words, if you have the following base template:

```
// base.html.twig
<html>
    <body>
       {{ block body }} 
       {{ endblock }}
    </body>
</html>
```

The following child template:

```
// child.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    // content
{% endblock %}
```

And the following controller action:

```
public function renderVariableAction()
{
    return $this->render('child.html.twig', [
        'hello' => 'Hello world',
    ]);
}
```

You can use `{{ hello }}` in both `base.html.twig` and `child.html.twig`.

**EDIT**

For a global variable:

```
// app/config/config.yml
# ...

twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        your_custom_var: "your_value"
```

You can't define a variable that is always assigned to a specific template, the variable must be rendered with it dynamically.

**Note** You can define global variables dynamically like this:

```
$this->get('twig')->addGlobal('entity', $entity);
```

So you can easily inject the same variable on `kernel.response` using an [EventListener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html).

See [global variables in templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html).

Comment: That doesn't really solve what I want to do though. I need to pass it every time base.html.twig is called upon. Is there a config setting where I can tell it to use this variable?

Comment: Thats great, is it possible to pass an entity this way?

Comment: I added a note in my edit that make you able to inject an object as global.